# How to use Jest in a Vuejs project with vuetify and vuex? node modules and vuetify problems

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I am currently testing a Vue project with Jest that uses Vuex and Vuetify in it. When testing something on any component, it gives me a bunch of errors of this nature:

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"

found in

---> <DashboardSlots>
       <StatusDashboard>
         <Root>


console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1884
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined   
        at VueComponent.mappedAction (D:\Users\ftg\git\DVBIP_GATEWAY_9\usr\nonius\webadmin\node_modules\vuex\dist\vuex.common.js:1052:34)
        at VueComponent.created (D:\Users\ftg\git\DVBIP_GATEWAY_9\usr\nonius\webadmin\src\components\DashboardSlots.vue:197:1)


console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
        [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-card> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make 
    sure to provide the "name" option.
        
        found in
        
        ---> <DashboardSlots>
               <StatusDashboard>
                 <Root>
```

And much more of these! I dont know why this is happening.

### This is my jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src/", "<rootDir>/test/"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue"
  ]
}
```

### This is my babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

### And this is my simple test (just printing something):

```
import Component from '@/components/StatusDashboard.vue';
import { mount , createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Actions from '@/vuex/actions.js'

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);
localVue.use(Vuetify, {});

localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('Component test', () => {

  it('check test', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component)
    const test = wrapper.vm.items
    console.log(test);
  })
})
```

Tried uninstalling node modules and reinstalling but did not solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You've setup `localVue`, but you haven't passed it into `mount()` as an [option](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#localvue).

It should be:

```js
mount(Component, { localVue })

//or
shallowMount(Component, { localVue })
```